# Как сделать что бы Javascript работал во всех блоках с одинаковыми id?

Tags: javascript

У меня на сайте есть скрип, который берет значение с тега span по Id и менят его значение. Так вот когда я поставил скрипт на вид материала, в каталоге материалов он меняет значение только первого материала. Как сделать что бы Javascript работал во всех блоках с одинаковыми id? Что бы он также менял значение в других материалах.

```html
<p style="display:none;" id="dr">62</p> <!--ЗДЕСЬ КУРС ДОЛЛАРА-->
<p id="rub" style="display:none;">12</p>
<p style="display: none;" id="oldprice">32</p>
<span style="color: #de0707; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500;" id="dollar"></span> <span style="color: #de0707; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500;" >руб.</span><br>
<span id="olddollar"></span> <span>руб. - розница</span>
<br>
<p style="display:none;" id="dr">62</p> <!--ЗДЕСЬ КУРС ДОЛЛАРА-->
<p id="rub" style="display:none;">12</p>
<p style="display: none;" id="oldprice">32</p>
<span style="color: #de0707; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500;" id="dollar"></span> <span style="color: #de0707; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500;" >руб.</span><br>
<span id="olddollar"></span> <span>руб. - розница</span>
<script>
var rub = document.getElementById("rub").innerHTML;
var dr = document.getElementById('dr').innerHTML;
var oldrub = document.getElementById("oldprice").innerHTML;
var dollar = document.getElementById('dollar');
var olddollar = document.getElementById('olddollar');
summa = (parseInt(oldrub * dr));
olddollar.innerHTML = summa;
result = (parseInt(rub * dr));
dollar.innerHTML = result;
</script>
```

Comment: Id на странице должны быть уникальными. Chrome в последней версии уже ругается в консоли, если несколько элементов имеют одинаковый id

Answer (score 2):

По спецификации - `id` должен иметь уникальное значение и не может повторяться на странице больше одного раза. Все остальные значения будут просто игнорироваться. Используйте другой селектор ( класс, поиск по атрибуту, тэг и т.д. )

Пример:

```
// список элементов с классом active
document.getElementsByClassName('active');
// список элементов у которых есть атрибут clickable
document.querySelectorAll('*[clickable]');
// все ссылки
document.querySelectorAll('a');
```

Comment: Прикрепил исходник